# How does function scope works with React?

Tags: reactjs

In [React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) comes the following example:

```
function tick() {
  const element = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
  ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

This code works, but I don't understand how is it possible that `ReactDOM.render` can call `element` if `const element` is inside the scope of `tick()`.

I understand that in javascript, variables (constants in this case) inside functions cannot be called from outside because of scoping. So, why or how does this React code works?

Comment: `ReactDOM.render` call is within the same scope as `element`. Both are inside `tick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just forgot that you also called `ReactDOM.render` in the scope of `tick`. this in turn means that both, `ReactDOM.render` and `const element` are both in the scope of your `tick` function

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

`tick` here is callback function called for defined every `1 secs` interval.

So,when `tick` is called,within its body there is  definition of `const element`.
So,its within the scope of `tick` and accessible.

Answer (score 0):

That is very true if `const element` wasn't in the scope of the function then it wouldn't have access to it but check here the function `tick()` is what is calling the `ReactDOM.render` and the constant `element` is defined inside `function tick()` so the render method of `react` totally has access to the `element` constant, check properly where the curl brace is closing, it is closing right after the function is called in the `setInterval(tick, 1000);`